# Eliminar solo las "O" finales pero respetar la letra en "HELLO"

Tags: regex, r

Me interesa eliminar la `O` final de cada palabra, excepto que esa palabra sea `HELLO`.

Estoy intentando esto pero no me resulta:

```
a <- c("HELLO DO","DO HELLO XO","HO")

gsub("[^HELLO]O\\>","",a)

[1] "HELLO "  " HELLO " "HO"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Coincidir también con HELLO**

La solución para este caso es:

1. efectivamente coincidir con la palabra `HELLO`, y usarla como texto de reemplazo (no reemplazar al fin y al cabo).

   Para coincidir con la *palabra*, usamos `\<HELLO\>`. `\<` y `\>` coinciden con la posición al inicio y al final de una palabra respectivamente.

   Pero, además, usamos un grupo, lo ponemos entre paréntesis como `(\<HELLO\>)` para que guarde el texto con el que coincidió. Luego, en el reemplazo, usamos `\1` para que lo vuelva a insertar.
2. o coincidir con la letra `O` al final de la palabra. Es decir, `O\>`.

   Cuando coincide con esta parte del regex, no estamos usando paréntesis, por lo que no se guarda ningún texto, y `\1` va a estar vacío, haciendo que el reemplazo sea por `""` (eliminándo esa letra).

Expresión regular:

```
(\<HELLO\>)|O\>
```

Reemplazo:

```
\1
```

Código:

```r
a <- c("HELLO DO","DO HELLO XO","XO","DOO CHELLO HELLOS HELLO BOOOO GO")

gsub("(\\<HELLO\\>)|O\\>","\\1",a)
```

Resultado:

```
[1] "HELLO D"                      "D HELLO X"                   
[3] "X"                            "DO CHELL HELLOS HELLO BOOO G"
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/bJzdFe

---

**2. O que no esté precedida**

Otra alternativa, es usando una inspección hacia atrás negativa (*negative lookbehind*), para asegurarnos de que la `O` no esté precedida por `\<HELL`.

```
(?<!\bHELL)O\b
```

Pero, para esto, tenemos que usar la sintaxis de Perl (pasando `perl=TRUE` en el último parámetro), que ofrece expresiones regulares mucho más poderosas.

En Perl, no existen `\<` ni `\>`, pero `\b` coincide con el inicio o final de una palabra.

Código:

```
a <- c("HELLO DO","DO HELLO XO","XO","DOO CHELLO HELLOS HELLO BOOOO GO")  
gsub("(?<!\\bHELL)O\\b","",a, perl=TRUE)
```

---

**¿Qué estaba mal en lo que intentaste?**

`[^HELLO]` es una clase de caracteres negada. Eso implica que coincide con 1 caracter, cualquier caracter excepto `H`,`E`, `L` u `O`. No es una forma de negar como estabas intentando hacerlo. Y no hay una forma *directa* de hacerlo, ya que las expresiones regulares son reglas para coincidir con el texto, no para lo contrario. Las soluciones a estos casos son siempre alternativas como la planteada arriba o usando inspecciones hacia atrás negativas (*negative lookbehinds*).

Comment: Buena idea  y muchas gracias he comprendido un poco mas este funcionamiento